# Relativistic mass increment

Tags: general-relativity, mass, relativity

Is the mass increment with an increase absolute velocity of a body, a direct consequence of energy to mass conversion

Comment: I am not quite understand your question. Would you mind make it clearer or elaborate on it?

Comment: 1) mass does **not** increase with velocity 2) a body cannot have absolute velocity (it is meaningless)

Comment: What is "an increase[d] absolute velocity?" There is no such thing.